# c# Short cut for enumerable list

Tags: c#

I have the following C# list code,

```
globalFaiths.AddAll( IEnumerable<Religion> religions )
```

I call it like this

```
globalFaiths.AddAll(new Religion[]{Bahai,Christian,Islam});
```

Is there a shoter way to send in `Bahai,Christian,Islam` to the `globalFaiths` function in c#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
globalFaiths.AddAll(new[]{Bahai,Christian,Islam});
```

If you change your method to use the [params keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) and an array, like so:

```
AddAll(params Religion[] religions)
```

You could then call this directly:

```
globalFaiths.AddAll(Bahai,Christian,Islam);
```

However, this requires changing the API of the collection class (`globalFaiths`'s type).  If changing this part of the code is an option, you might also want to consider using `AddRange` instead of `AddAll`, as this would more closely match the framework (ie: [`List<T>.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)).

Comment: i would just use `new[] {}` its not that much more verbose as the other option and it doesnt require an API change.

Comment: @StanR. I would, too, which is why I included it first - though the params is often fairly useful and nice to include in an API - it really depends on how this is going to be used, though.

Comment: @StanR.: One thought: `new[]{}` is not much overhead in terms of characters, but it is ackward to type. That might be reason enough to introduce a `params` version of a method.

Answer (score 3):

You could change your method like this:

```
public void AddAll(params Religion[] religions) 
{
    // ...
}
```

You could than use it like this:

```
globalFaiths.AddAll(Bahai, Christian, Islam);
```

BTW: If you would make this change, it would be better to name the method `Add`, as it would also be possible to pass only one religion.

If you can't change your code, another option would be an extension method:

```
public static void Add(this Faiths faiths, params Religion[] religions)
{
    faiths.AddAll(religions);
}
```

Granted, that might be a little overkill if you only call that method once or twice in your code.

Comment: I voted this up, but I forgot to mention I can't change that part of the code.

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com: Please check update with an idea for this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the `AddAll` method you can do something like this:

```
AddAll(params Religion[] religions)
```

And than add items like this:

```
globalFaiths.AddAll(Bahai,Christian,Islam);
```